# SQL Code: Counting the number of items that meets multiple requirements

Tags: sql, database, select, teradata

I'm trying to get a total volume count of items that meet multiple requirements. In this table, each product sold has a distinct ID. Each product, however, can be paired with multiple attributes (we'll call these colors). For example: product with ID# 1234 can have attributes blue and orange, both listed under the attribute column (in a many rows-to-one link to product ID#).

What I am looking to do is count the number of products that have certain combinations of attributes. For example, how many products have orange and blue, not just orange or blue. To make this more complicated, I cannot pull the total number of product ID's, I will have to count them. Suffice it to say that I am pulling for a time period in which there were hundreds of millions of products sold, all with varying attribute combinations. To further complicate things, there are multiple codes per color. Blue, for example, can be coded either 01, or 950.

Is there a way that I can craft a SQL statement that will let me count the number of products that satisfy specific attribute combinations? Such as, pulling the volume for:
Orange and Blue
Blue and Green
Green and Yellow
etc.?

I am at my wits end, and need some guidance!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific? What have you tried? Can you post your query? Or a sample table? Expected results?

Comment: Do you want to count multiple combinations in a single query? How many attributes can be grouped together?

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from table where Attribute in (01,950) and Attribute in (02, 951)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select ProductId
from ProductAttributes pa
group by ProductId
having sum(case when Attribute in ('01', '950') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when Attribute in ('02', '951') then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If you want the number of attributes, put this in a subquery:

```
select count(*) 
from (select ProductId
      from ProductAttributes pa
      group by ProductId
      having sum(case when Attribute in ('01', '950') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when Attribute in ('02', '951') then 1 else 0 end) > 0
     ) t;
```

There are other approaches, but the `having` clause is very flexible for all types of conditions you might want on the attributes within each product.